# DELPHI XE7 - [unit scope "Bde" indicates Win32 only] Error al compilar

Tags: delphi, compilacion

Tengo dudas respecto un componente que intento instalar en delphi XE7, mas concretamente el **LMD VCL 2014.** Resulta que muchos de los paquetes compilaron sin problemas pero algunos relacionados a Bde.DBTables y DBTables me estan tirando error. al compilar me salta especificamente este error y me señala en el codigo esta seccion.

{$IFDEF LMDCOMP16}Bde.DBTables{$ELSE}DBTables{$ENDIF};  // TypeInfo(TConfigMode)

En la consola tambien marca este error:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] LMD_RegMainDB.pas(69): F1026 File not found: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\3ras_partes\LMD VCL Complete 2014.3\source\packages\d21\Bde.DBTables.dcu' (unit scope "Bde" indicates Win32 only)
```

Tengo todo lo relacionado a LMD agregado a la libreria de Delphi por ende no sabria como proceder con el problema.

Comment: ¿Para qué plataforma estás compilando? El mensaje parece indicar que lo estás haciendo para una plataforma distinta de Win32, y la dependencia (BDE.*) solo está diponible para Win32 (Vale recordar que el BDE ha sido marcado como obsoleto desde hace unos 15 años, por lo menos, por lo que su uso, a estas alturas está más que NO recomendado).

Comment: Todo en el IDE (Delphi XE 7) indica que estoy compilando para windows 32bits. En cuanto al BDE agradezco tu informacion, no estaba enterado. De todas maneras solo quiero instalar la totalidad del componente para poder compilar otro proyecto que aparentemente hace uso de algunas cosas del LMD

Comment: El mensaje de error indica que no estás compilando para otra plataforma, te sugiero hacer un doble chequeo sobre el tema. Por otro lado, muchos suites de componentes son lo suficientemente modulares para excluir partes que no necesitas. Si tu proyecto no hace uso de BDE, sugiero que investigues si es posible instalar los componentes de marras sin soporte/dependencias para/hacia BDE, lo cual te evitará estos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Al final lo deje sin instalar BDE, por suerte el proyecto no tenia uso de nada relacionado a eso asique no hubo problemas para compilar. Muchas gracias por la informacion de todas maneras